# WebScrapping with python I can't collect data from other pages only from the first one

Tags: list

my script captures the data from the first page, passes it to the second page, does not do the scrapping and goes back to the first page.
I wanted some help getting the data from the pages, it's for a college assignment.
I'm using this script:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (2)\\chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url_base = 'http://ww3.fepam.rs.gov.br/licenciamento/area3/listaRazao.asp?area=3&buscar=2&tipoBusca=municipio&municipio=9999999&razao=&ramo=112,14'
numero_paginas = 7
dados_totais = []
for pagina in range(1, numero_paginas + 1):
url = url_base + f'&pagina={pagina}'

    
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)  
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='item')
    
    
    for div in divs:
        razao_social = div.find('li', class_='esq').next_sibling.next_sibling.text.strip()
        cnpj = div.find('li', class_='dir').text.strip()
        endereco = div.find_all('li', class_='dir')[1].text.strip()
        bairro = div.find_all('li', class_='dir')[2].text.strip()
        municipio = div.find_all('li', class_='dir')[3].text.strip()
    
       
        dados_totais.append([razao_social, cnpj, endereco, bairro, municipio])
    
   
    try:
        proxima_pagina = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'R')))
        proxima_pagina.click()
        time.sleep(3)  
    except:
        break

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(dados_totais, columns=['Razão Social', 'CNPJ', 'Endereço', 'Bairro', 'Município'])

print(df)
```

I want help with what I'm doing wrong, I'm 1 week and I don't find a solution, any help is welcome